# With Elsa Workflows 3.0, is there a way to customize the blocks / activities with icons and also the diagrams themselves?

Tags: elsa-workflows

ELSA 3.0
I have been trying to customize Elsa workflows and to add custom activity, was able to customize to a certain extent by adding new activity, but wasn't able to get the color scheme set as per the activity category. Also need to customize the activity with just icon instead of the mud button / text.

Tried customizing by adding custom activity but wasn't able to get the styling / color on the activity block. Also wanted to have an image / icon instead of the button/ text on the activity menu.

I do see documentation is still in progress and the roadmap has somewhat changed. But how far away is support for BPMN?

Thanks!